# import configurable products csv

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, csv

I'm trying to import a csv which contains both configurable and simple products. I'm using the built-in "Import all products" profile, and using this example:

```
"attribute_set","type","category_ids","sku","has_options","name","dimension","collezione","url_key","url_path","price","weight","status","visibility","tax_class_id","tipologia","description","qty","product_name","product_type_id","variante","associated","super_products_sku"
```

I get them all imported but the ones I want to be associated are not.
What do I need to do to achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

From your description it looks like you are using the old DataFlow import tool.
This does not support associating simple products to configurable products out of the box, even though it has often been implemented in third party modules.

Since Magento 1.5 however there also is the ImportExport tool available, which does support configurable products completely.
If I'm right with the assumption that you are using DataFlow, I suggest you use the ImportExport tool instead.
It can be found in the admin area under *System > Import/Export > Import*.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/importing-configurable-products). It states:

> The products that are associated with a configurable product are usually created directly from within the configurable product record. However, it is also possible to import existing, simple product records into a configurable product, provided that the data meets the following requirements:
>
> - The simple products do not have custom options.
> - All products have unique SKU numbers.
> - Each simple product must be based on the same attribute set that was used to create the configurable product record.
> - There is at least one super attribute assigned to the configurable product and the same super attribute is included in the simple product.